# android socket internet

Tags: java, android, sockets

i got a little problem with my little application by using java Sockets.

if i start my Sockert-Server on pc and i'm connected withmy phone via wifi in the same network by using the (intern) network IP i can send some stuff to my server.

But if i try to send a message via the mobile internet connection,it doesn´t work..there is also no error or something else :/

Here is my android class:

```
public class Sockets extends Activity {
EditText textOut;
EditText ipAddress;
TextView textIn;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_socket);

     textOut = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textout);
     Button buttonSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
     ipAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ipAddress);
     buttonSend.setOnClickListener(buttonSendOnClickListener);
 }

 Button.OnClickListener buttonSendOnClickListener
 = new Button.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    new DatagrammClient(ipAddress.getText().toString(),textOut.getText().toString()).execute("");
    textOut.setText("");

}};

private static class DatagrammClient extends android.os.AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    final static String LOGIN = "LOGIN";
    final static String LOGOUT = "LOGOUT";
    static int port = 1234;
    static int length = 1024; // Länge eines Pakets

    static DatagramSocket socket = null;
    static InetAddress ia = null;
    static DatagramPacket packet;

    String hostname = "";
    String msg ="";

    public DatagrammClient(String hostname,String msg) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    /**
     * Send the login package and open socket
     * 
     * @param servername
     * @throws IOException,UnknownHostEception 
     */
    private static void connectToServer(String servername) throws IOException,UnknownHostException{

        packet = null;
        byte[] ba = LOGIN.getBytes();       

        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
            ia = InetAddress.getByName(servername);
            packet = new DatagramPacket(ba, ba.length, ia, port);
            Log.d("servername",servername);
            Log.d("Internetaddress",ia.toString());
            Log.d("SOCKET",socket.toString());
            // sende Anmeldung
            socket.send(packet);

        } catch (SocketException se) {
            Log.d("SocketException",se.toString());
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException he) {
            Log.d("UnknownHost: ",he.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("IOException: ",e.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void sendMessage(String message, String hostname) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
        //if (socket == null){
        DatagrammClient.connectToServer(hostname);
        //}
        DatagrammClient.sendMessageToServer(message);

        DatagrammClient.readMessageFromServer();

        //Close connection -> Send logout Package?
    }

    private static void readMessageFromServer(){
        // Lesen der empfangenen Pakete erfolgt in eigenem Thread
        LeseThread lt = new LeseThread( socket );
    }

    private static void sendMessageToServer(String message){
        byte[] ba = null;
        try {
            if (!message.equals(LOGOUT)) {
                // message = br.readLine();
                ba = message.getBytes();
                packet.setData(ba, 0, ba.length);
                socket.send(packet);
                Log.d("Message:",packet.toString());
            } else {
                ba = LOGOUT.getBytes();
                packet.setData(ba, 0, ba.length);
                socket.send(packet);

                // Exit the system -> do we need to close the socket clientside?
                //socket.close();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Ausnahmefehler: " + e);
            Log.d("IOEXCEPTION_MESSAGE_TO_SERVER:",e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            DatagrammClient.sendMessage(msg, hostname);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Error: ",e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
}
```

The permission to use the INTERNET is set in the Manifest..

Comment: I hope that when on mobile internet connection you use a public webserver IP.